# Angular-cli ng serve not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Error is displaying when using ng serve or npm start command ,ng new is working.Previously it was working but now its not ,i have installed nodejs and angular-cli correctly.Thanks in advance.
Error shown is:

```
Cannot read property 'glob' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'glob' of null
    at ObjectSchemaTreeNode._set (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:224:131)
    at new ObjectSchemaTreeNode (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:209:14)
    at OneOfSchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:148:26)
    at OneOfSchemaTreeNode._typesPrototype.schema.oneOf.map (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:161:25)
    at Array.map (native)
    at OneOfSchemaTreeNode (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:160:48)
    at ArraySchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:148:26)
    at ArraySchemaTreeNode._set (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:286:39)
    at new ArraySchemaTreeNode (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:267:14)
    at ObjectSchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:148:26)
    at ObjectSchemaTreeNode._set (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:224:45)
    at new ObjectSchemaTreeNode (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:209:14)
    at ArraySchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:148:26)
    at ArraySchemaTreeNode._set (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:286:39)
    at new ArraySchemaTreeNode (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:267:14)
    at RootSchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:148:26)
    at RootSchemaTreeNode._set (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:224:45)
    at RootSchemaTreeNode.ObjectSchemaTreeNode (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:209:14)
    at RootSchemaTreeNode (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-tree.js:307:9)
    at GeneratedSchemaClass.SchemaClassBase (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-class-factory.js:53:29)
    at GeneratedSchemaClass (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema\src\schema-class-factory.js:144:13)
    at new CliConfig (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:18:24)
    at Function.fromConfigPath (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:81:16)
    at Function.fromProject (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config.js:90:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:7:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Class.includedCommands (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\addon\index.js:15:16)
    at F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:287:61
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Project.addonCommands (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:286:15)
    at Project.eachAddonCommand (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:321:30)
    at module.exports (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\lookup-command.js:33:13)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:46:26)
    at tryCatch (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:12)
    at invokeCallback (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:553:13)
    at publish (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:521:7)
    at flush (F:\projects\app1\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2373:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: How to uninstall it Sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like missing dependencies. Try removing `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.

Comment: Open command prompt and go in your project directory. Then run `npm install`

Comment: he meant remove folder `node_modules` from your project directory, then run `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, I had run ng unit in system root directory by mistake. Once I had delete all the angular-cli files it was working

What I had done to resolve on windows-10 system.

1. Open cmd.
2. Run dir. (in Linux or mac its ls).
3. If you find **angular-cli** files just delete.

And it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on 1.3.1. I also change the dev in the package from `angular/cli 131` to `angular cli 1.7.4` (may be optional)

Verify that you own the directory (`chown groupe:user directory` on ubuntu) and try root launch for the ng (sudo)

or / and remove the node dir and `-lock.json`, run `npm i` and launch or `sudo launch ng`

Answer (score 0):

I know now that u need too own the rights on the directory not to have problem with sudo and install permissions. u won't need sudo. look at npm update also.

chown user:user /directory -> 4 ubuntu